# In OpenERP my timezone aware datetimes are still being treated as UTC -- why?

Tags: datetime, timezone, odoo

I understand that OpenERP since 6.1 decided to exclusively use the UTC timezone for storage of datetimes, but why does it ignore the timezone of my tz-aware datetimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in OpenERP](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1257807) probably since 6.1.  [This patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1257807/+attachment/3923215/+files/datetime_timezone.patch) (against 7.0) fixes it.

For the curious, the heart of the fix is a few lines to the `.../openerp/osv/fields.py` module:

```
UTC = pytz.timezone('UTC')
.
.
.
class datetime(_column):
    ...
    _symbol_c = '%s'
    def _symbol_f(symb):
        if symb is None or symb == False:
            return None
        elif isinstance(symb, unicode):
            symb = symb.encode('utf-8')
        if not isinstance(symb, str):
            # had better be something that quacks like a datetime
            if symb.tzinfo is not None:
                symb = symb.astimezone(UTC)
            symb = symb.strftime(tools.DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        return symb
    _symbol_set = (_symbol_c, _symbol_f)

...

class function(_column):
    ...
    if type == 'datetime':
        self._symbol_c = datetime._symbol_c
        self._symbol_f = datetime._symbol_f
        self._symbol_set = datetime._symbol_set
```