# OpenERP logs are in UTC -- how to get them in the same timezone as the server?

Tags: logging, timezone, odoo

My OpenERP logs are showing timestamps in the UTC timezone, even though the actual server is in the America/Los_Angeles timezone.  This makes comparing the OpenERP logs against any of the other logs on the server a pain.

How can I get the OpenERP logs to be in the correct timezone?

Comment: Putting log files in UTC is always a smart decision.  If you're going to use local time then you should also store the offset on each entry so you can distinguish between [the two different periods during the fall-back daylight saving time transition](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).  I don't know the specifics about OpenERP, but if you need help converting from UTC to a specific time zone, please provide more details.

Comment: Also, is this somehow a coding question? I'm tempted to vote it to be closed as off topic.  Can you explain?  And why [the dup post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381970)?

Comment: @MattJohnson: I can certainly agree with putting the offset in there, but not with storing the textual logs in UTC.  I don't think in UTC time, I think in local time -- even if the local time is somewhere besides where I'm at.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Both these questions deal with timezones, but not with the same aspect of OpenERP's handling of timezones, and they are not resolved with the same code changes.  The code to address both issues are in the patches linked to by both issues (I didn't think it would be appropriate to dump a large patch in the answer).

Comment: @MattJohnson: And before you ask, UTC is not local time for anybody I deal with.  ;)

Comment: It isn't local time for most people, even in Europe. :)  But it is a common convention, and eliminates DST issues.  But you can certainly use a local time as long as you store the offset also.  Log your timestamps like this:  2013-12-31T01:23:45.678-08:00.  (This is the recommended profile of [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) that's described in [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a side effect of the decision to force the OpenERP server into the UTC timezone.  There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1257827) with [a patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1257827/+attachment/3923251/+files/timezone.patch) against the 7.0 sources that will get the logs back into the proper timezone.

For the curious, the heart of the fix is to replace `logging.Formatter.converter` with a function smart enough to adjust back to the local timezone:

```
def adjust_logging_timezone():
    logger_tz = pytz.timezone(config['timezone'] or detect_server_timezone())
    if logger_tz.zone != 'UTC':
        def converter(secs=None):
            dt = datetime(*time.localtime(secs)[:6])
            dt = UTC.localize(dt).astimezone(logger_tz)
            return dt.timetuple()
        logging.Formatter.converter = staticmethod(converter)
```